# cryto.createHash sha512 with hexDigest input type

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, hex, sha512

I am trying to get the same result I obtain at http://jssha.sourceforge.net/

where

I have the word 'testing' in question:

```
var word = 'testing';
var hex = toHex(word); // '740065007300740069006e006700';
```

on jssha when selecting `input type` as HEX with the value of the `hex` variable and SHA-512 I get the following result:

```
6e42b2c2a6351036b78384212774135d99d849da3066264983e495b5f74dc922e3d361b8ea9c8527169757233ed0bd4e56b2c42aab0a21bbcca67219dc53b472
```

although I can't achieve the same result with [nodejs crypto module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/crypto.html).

```
require('crypto').createHash('sha512').update(hex).digest('hex')
```

outputs:

```
9ad6d9053c6c420fe61ec2fffd094e3a325bc71708e18232fd764a5eb30315e38464e620ef0b55b92fbf6c809838652a72d9412b0398b28d61ca432962451de2
```

So I am wondering how can I get the same result as [jssha](http://jssha.sourceforge.net/) using crypto module?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"testing" in hex is 74657374696e67 if you use utf8 which is pretty much standard. What your toHex method returns assumes utf16.

For that hash, the website says:

```
521b9ccefbcd14d179e7a1bb877752870a6d620938b28a66a107eac6e6805b9d0989f45b5730508041aa5e710847d439ea74cd312c9355f1f2dae08d40e41d50
```

Do this in node.js to hash a hex string:

```
require('crypto').createHash('sha512').update(
  new Buffer("74657374696e67", "hex")
).digest('hex')
```

Node gives you the same hash. Oh, and this also gives you the same hash:

```
require('crypto').createHash('sha512').update("testing").digest('hex')
```

Comment: thanks @thejh, it seems `new Buffer("74657374696e67", "hex")` method returns `Unknown encoding` for me. Also, is there any way to make it use utf-16 instead 8. Sorry I guess I am stuck with this encoding since it is from an external web service.

Comment: @ludicco: Sure, you can just do the same with a utf16 hex string. The "unknown encoding" is because you're using an old version of node, use 0.5.10 and change to 0.6.0 when it's available.

Comment: thanks again @thejh, the only problem is that this instance is running on heroku, and I'm afraid they only support 0.47 by now? in this case I am not sure if the method you've mentioned would be able work? if you have any idea on how I could make this work, it would be really appreciated ;)

Comment: No idea, you might want to ask in #heroku on freenode.net. As a workaround, you can use Buffer.fromHex from https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-buffertools .

Comment: Do `require("buffertools")` at the top of your file and replace `new Buffer("74657374696e67", "hex")` with `Buffer.fromHex("74657374696e67")`