# SHA256-CRYPT / SHA512-CRYPT in node.js

Tags: node.js, sha256, crypt, sha512

I use dovecot as my mail transfer agent and I aim to use the [strongest password scheme](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes) which is supported by my system: **SHA512-CRYPT** or **SHA256-CRYPT** (BLF-CRYPT doesn't work).

For my own written webinterface I look for a function or library in node.js for hashing a password (with SHA***-CRYPT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider checking: https://github.com/mvo5/sha512crypt-node which contains a implementation for sha512crypt in JS. Its very new but passes the testvectors from the glibc reference implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [my fork of shacrypt](https://github.com/vlasky/shacrypt) - a Node.js addon that supports SHA-256 crypt and SHA-512 crypt password hashing.

I extended it to:

- Support asynchronous operation where computation is performed in Node.js's libuv thread pool, so it won't block the event loop.
- Allow the module to be built under Windows

You will need to have C++ build tools installed on your system to successfully install the package. If you are running under Windows, you can download [Microsoft's Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

Link:
https://github.com/vlasky/shacrypt

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this page:
[cryto.createHash sha512 with hexDigest input type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956695/cryto-createhash-sha512-with-hexdigest-input-type)

You can use crypto.createHash function, but why SHA512? Are you sure you need it for your website?

Comment: SHA512 != SHA512-CRYPT (includes automatically rounds and salting)

Comment: Have not seen any public implemention of this algorithm in nodejs